# Count Elements Conditionally In HQL

Tags: nhibernate, hql

I have an HQL query that returns projections of an entity including a count of the a certain child collection.

```
select t.Id as TagId, t.Name as Name, count(elements(t.Documents)) as Count 
from Tag t
group by t.Id, t.Name, t.User
having t.User.Id = :userId"
```

It works except I need to place a condition on the count.  I only want to count Documents where Trashed = false for the document.

I seem to have a mental block on how to do this.  I am using NHibernate 3.0.  I would be equally happy with ICriteria or Linq query.

**UPDATE**: Here is the fully correct query:

```
select t.Id as TagId, t.Name as Name, sum(case when d.Trashed = false then 1 else 0 end) as Count 
from Tag t
left join t.Documents d
group by t.Id, t.Name, t.User
having t.User.Id = :userId and sum(case when d.Trashed = false then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC, something like this should work (where d is an alias to the Documents collection):

```
sum(case when d.Trashed = false then 1 else 0 end) as Count
```

Comment: don't you mean <<sum(case when d.Trashed = false then count(elements(t.Documents)) else 0 end) as Count>> ??

Comment: Please do not approve wiki edits which contain plagiarized content. http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11291699 is a verbatim copy + paste from http://jquerymy.com/ - Pop in by http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers if you'd like to discuss